# Packaging a CTI enabled Lightning application

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, package, cti, opencti

We have a working implementation of FastCall running on Lightning Open CTI. So we want to deliver it to our subscribers, and if possible include the Lightning app with "Open CTI Softphone" option enabled. Since we already include the appropriate Call Center to work in lightning as well.

We are able to package the Lightning app, but we can't find the way to package it with Softphone enabled (i.e., avoid having to check "OpenCTI Softphone" under the App Manager > Our App > App Options).

Doing some research over the new metadata components we found that the Lightning apps have a new property CtiUtilBar and that CtiUtilBar is a FlexiPage component that seems to be created by the platform when Lightning is enabled.

We tried packaging the app with CtiUtilBar but when it's installed in the subscriber's org, the Softphone is not enabled, and it is not possible to enable the option by hand because the app component is managed.

Maybe Salesforce doesn't support what we want to in this release of Lightning OpenCTI?

If so, what would you recommend in this case, subscribers have to manually create the Lightning app and enable the softphone?

Thanks for your answers & feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way.  We've pushed Salesforce to make Open CTI support enabled by default for Lightning apps but haven't found anyone who is responsive.